# java : avoid printing new line for the last line of the output

Tags: java, formatting

I'm printing the difference between long numbers from a file and I'm listing the results within a loop. But I don't want to print the newline for the last result that gets printed.

Here's the code that prints the results :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc;
        long a = 0, b = 0;
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            File file = new File(input.nextLine());

            input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String split[] = line.split("\\s+");
                a = Long.parseLong(split[0]);
                b = Long.parseLong(split[1]);
                System.out.println(Math.abs(a-b));
            }
            input.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

The output which I get now is :

```
2
71293781685339
12345677654320
```

and this has a newline in the end.
How do I avoid the new line while printing last result? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is still input left to be processed before printing a new line

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String split[] = line.split("\\s+");
    a = Long.parseLong(split[0]);
    b = Long.parseLong(split[1]);
    System.out.print(Math.abs(a-b)); //Print without a newline

   if (input.hasNextLine()) {
       System.out.println();//Print new line if there is more input left
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the first line using `System.out.println(line)`, and print the rest lines using `System.out.print("\n" + line)`.